# getting the "right" indentation via my c++-mode-hook

Tags: indentation

Using GNU Emacs 24.5.1

My c++-mode hook has `(c-set-style "cc-mode")`.  This works fairly well for me, with the following exceptions:

First of all: `try`-blocks are indented

```
int main()
   try 
      {
        //...
      }
   catch (...)
      {
        // ...
      }
```

I would prefer

```
int main()
try 
{
        //...
}
catch (...)
{
        // ...
}
```

In addition, when using `enum class`, I get

```
enum class Month {
  jan=1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec
    };
```

It would be more natural for the closing brace to be flush left:

```
enum class Month {
  jan=1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec
};
```

I have also tried all the other built-in styles.  The two that work best are `cc-mode` and `stroustrup`, but neither give me the behavior I would like.

Suggestions? Many thanks!